# How to pass a variable in VBA to HTML code?

Tags: html, excel, vba, outlook

I am using Excel VBA to generate an email in Outlook.

I would like to pass a variable value to the HTML code I am using to generate emails. The HTML code is lives in `Sheet1!$A$1`

How can I pass a variable value from a subroutine to the HTML code? I don't want to write out my HTML code in a module as writing it in VBA is painful!

VBA

```
Sub foo()
Dim myCustomVariable as string
myCustomVariable = "John Smith"
End Sub
```

HTML in `Sheet1!$A$1`

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Hello "myCustomVariable "</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate your tags and variables with `&`

---

```
.HTMLBody = "<p>" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") & "</p>"
```